# How to use a progress dialog for `AESCrypt.encrypt`

Tags: android, android-layout, encryption

I want to use [progress dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5U3H.png) in function in Android Studio. This form will appear until the code is executed:

```
protected boolean encryptFile() {

    /*
     * set input file name
     */
    String encryptFileName = mEditText.getText().toString();
    /*
     * set hint
     */
    String hint = mHintText.getText().toString();
    if(hint.isEmpty()){hint=null;}
    /*
     * set password
     */
    String password = mPassText.getText().toString();
    /*
     * select encrypted file name
     */
    String encryptedFileName = mEditText.getText().toString()+".enc";
    if(hint!=null){
        encryptedFileName = mEditText.getText().toString() + "(hint-" +hint+ ").enc";
    }
    /*
     * Encrypt
     */
    try {
        AESCrypt crypt = new AESCrypt(password);
        crypt.encrypt(2, encryptFileName, encryptedFileName);
        return true;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}


public void encrypt(int version, String fromPath, String toPath)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
        debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));

        debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

        encrypt(version, in, out);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you read about creating a dialog in Android.

Comment: Hi paria, this Q/A site is for specific questions. Your code doesn't contain any question, and it doesn't show what you've tried and why you are stuck. Code requests in itself are off topic. I've formatted your question none-the-less, please take a look at the edit so you know how to improve next questions. For now I've voted to close the question, but if you manage to actually ask a question then I gladly remove it again